# Proper circuit for a solenoid being triggered by a relay with occasional misfires

Tags: relay, 12v, solenoid

12V relay question…

I built a homemade pinball controller for my PC using a standard, 5 V USB encoder for the controls. I wanted to add some haptic feedback, so I decided to add a few 12 V solenoids and run them off of said 5v relays.

Here are the relays: DaFuRui 5 V Relay Module，8Pack 1 Channel Relay Module 5 V Relay Board with Optocoupler Support High/Low Level Trigger for Arduino Relay https://a.co/d/4fNcPTz

So, since the relay was 5 V, I simply powered it from the USB encoder board which has dedicated outputs for 5 V.

If I were to have this same set up, but use a 12 V relay, I am sure the supplied 5 V from the USB board won’t trigger it, so, my question is, is there a way to still feed the board 12 V like it wants (I’ll just use a separate power source), but allow the 5 V button press trigger that the encoder provides to trigger the solenoid?

The reason I ask this is that the way the relay wants to be set up is to combine the trigger wire with the DC+ in for the relay. Since the arcade buttons are designed to work in 5 V, I was afraid this would shoot 5 V back upstream to the board if I have a 12 V power source for the 12 V relay.

I hope I explained that well.

Here’s a video of my setup: https://odysee.com/solenoid:7

Here it is back in the box: https://odysee.com/pushpush:7

Also, I seem to get occasional misfires where the relay board will click and receive the signal, but the solenoid won’t fire. When this happens, I have verified that there is no voltage being sent to the solenoid according to a multimeter. It also seems that depending on the location of the solenoid, the misfires become works. Possibly an EMF issue?

Also, when the solenoid DOES fire, I notice that the multimeter shows about 11.7 V as opposed to the 12+ V that I meter on the actual power supply. Is that because of the load or resistance reducing that power a bit?

I have also ordered a few more different types of relays that will arrive this even - just in case I have faulty boards, or that they aren’t the best style.

Comment: Welcome to EE. It seems not to be a complicated circuit, but would you care to make a diagram or schematics over it anyway?

Comment: Modules are very low-priced. Looks like the relay on the board is 5 V only coil. Not 12 V coil. I'm not sure from your writing if you are considering applying 12 V to the coil and using a 5 V signal or if you are asking about 12 V on the NC/NO side. But those relays do not look like their NO/NC output sides are spec'd for DC, at all. Just AC contacts from what I see. Down-rating them for DC use might be reasonable. But you may need to check the manufacturer datasheet, too. You want to supply 12 V for the solenoids. Is that right? (Not the relay coil.)

Comment: Just checked the [datasheet](https://denkovi.com/Documents/JQC-3FF-S-Z.pdf). It appears that the contacts are rated for 10 A at 28 VDC. So that's okay. The coil side does pull over 70 mA. But it looks like you only have two of these to worry about. So under 150 mA, total. You are using WAGO ties and adequate dimensioned wiring. Are you using a zener+diode for discharging the solenoids? Or how are you allowing the solenoid to discharge its energy?

Comment: Hello - thanks for the details so far. I do not have a diode yet. I was thinking of putting one inline with the solenoid so that there’s no back flow of electricity after it’s deactivated. 

Also, since this is for pinball, rapid firing and button presses in quick succession are important.

Comment: Ideally, I want to use a 5v input signal (the arcade button) to trigger the relate to activate the 12V solenoid. The other relays that I just ordered are these:

YWBL-WH Relay Module One Way 30A Optocoupler Isolation Relay Module High Power Relay High/Low Level Trigger YYG-2(5VDC) (1) https://a.co/d/97LC7Bn

Comment: ELECTRONICS-SALON DPDT Signal Relay Module, 5Vdc, RY5W-K Relay. Has Assembled. https://a.co/d/aU978Nk

HiLetgo 5V 1 Channel Self Locking Bistable One Button Start/Stop Self-Locking Relay Module Relay Switch for MCU Control https://a.co/d/f4Wc4GV

Comment: Relay Module One Way 30A Optocoupler Isolation Relay Module High Power Relay High/Low Level Trigger YYG-2(12VDC) https://a.co/d/abQHDXX



In the end, all I need to happen is that whenever I press the arcade button, I would like the solenoid to click/make noise. This is often used in virtual pinball cabinets to simulate actual flippers. 

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm thinking [along these lines.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtwgI.png). If you use a zener rated with a reasonably high voltage, the solenoid should release quite quickly. Otherwise

Comment: I have some of these. Would they work? https://a.co/d/1P7c8A2

Comment: They aren't zeners. So the more you can stack in series, aligned the same, and placed so that they do NOT conduct when the solenoid is ON... the better. One is enough. But will only drop a small voltage. Which means the solenoid takes longer to relax. The more you stack in series the better, since the solenoid releases more quickly then.

Comment: Thanks so much. I’ll look into that. Look at this video at the 1:10 mark. This person has a diode wired up directly inline with both legs of the solenoid. 
https://youtu.be/MCHKcMlRTaM?si=FbpwKkbBbHxZymIc